# Jquery ui, call start drag manually

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drag

In Jquery UI I can configure an element as draggable by invoking

```
$("#drag").draggable();
```

But is there a way to start and stop the drag functions manually from another function? Ie

```
someOtherFunction = function() {
  $("#drag").startdrag();
}
yetAnotherFunction = function() {
  $("#drag").stopdrag();
}
```

Comment: maybe you're interested in scrollTo because I don't beleive draggable can move an object without mouse interaction?

Comment: I never said I don't want to use the mouse. I have to invoke the drag outside the div because it should be initiated from within a Flash file using FScommand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answers above seem overcomplicated.

```
$('.nonDraggableObjectWhichTriggersDrag').mousedown(function(e) {
    $('.draggableObject').trigger(e); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that this would have worked in my original project (since it involved Flash and `fsCommand`), but it's the closest to a working solution that's been posted. In the project I ended up putting the draghandler above the Flash file, and putting divs over the flash buttons calling the flash commands through `fsCommand`. Not pretty but it worked.

Comment: +1 -- I know this comment is a bit late but `triggerHandler(e)` should probably be used instead. When I used `trigger`, I ended up with a stack overflow because of the way I had other functions/DOM hooked up. Changing it to `triggerHandler` resolved this issue because no bubbling occurred. `triggerHandler` will also be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Drag start is started via script looking at mouse events.  mouse down followed by a mouse move.  If you can simulate those mouse movements via Javascript (I don't know where, how, or even if this is possible), then it should fire off the start of a drag.

Note: just found that YUI has a way to simulate mouse moves and mouse clicks.  Check out http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuitest/#useractions

Comment: That sounds too complex. Maybe this would be easier to accomplish with other libraries, then? Maybe prototype.js or something similar?

Comment: Go for it.  If prototype can simulate mouse movement events, then it's going to be just as "difficult" as with yui.

Answer (score 1):

to stop the dragging you just have to return false in the dragging callback, something like this:

```
$("#unlock-handle").draggable({axis:'x', containment:'parent', drag:onDrag});

...

var onDrag = function(e) {      
    if ($(this).position().left > 200) return false;
};
```

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find a way to trigger dragging manually, but I have found a workaround for my similar situation.

I had this situation with two overlapping images (see image below), both partially transparent. In draggable's start(event) I wanted to check if it hits transparent pixels. If so, I looked under it for another element to see if that one was hit. And if it was, I wanted to initiate its dragging.

[image]

Solution? I reorder images on mousemove, and draggable is then triggered for that topmost image.

For pixel-precise element selection, see my another answer in: [registering clicks on an element that is under another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148424/registering-clicks-on-an-element-that-is-under-another-element/13426070#13426070)