# Detect mouse over bezier or quadratic curve

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect mouseover of certain points within an HTML canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221347/detect-mouseover-of-certain-points-within-an-html-canvas)

I have some Bezier and/or quadratic curves drawn on an HTML5 canvas.

How can I detect when the mouse is over a curve and select it when the mouse is clicked?

Is there a quick way of checking if the mouse pointer lies over a curve?

I'm using the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit and JQuery.

Comment: This library will give you exactly what you want easily and cross-browser: http://raphaeljs.com/