# What is wrong in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am using a div and want it to move with mouse coordinates. I don't know what is wrong. Or the method I am using is wrong. Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <script></script>
    <style>
        #box{
            background:cyan;
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body onLoad="placeBox()">

    <div id="box"></div>

    <script>
    function placeBox(){
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        var d = document.getElementById('box');
        d.style.position = "absolute";
        d.style.left = x+'px';
        d.style.top =  y+'px';
    }
    setInterval("placeBox()", 1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `event` is probably undefined; secondly, always post your questions with the error code displayed on the Console tab.

Comment: You're trying to read an event object in response to a time interval instead of an event that has coordinates.

Comment: What error do you get in the console.log()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a timeout, use an event callback for the mousemove event. Something like this, to keep it short:

```
function placeBox(event){
    var d = document.getElementById('box');
    d.style.position = "absolute"; // This could be set through CSS instead
    d.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
    d.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", placeBox);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwnzj/1/)

*Notice that `addEventListener` is not supported by older browsers, so if you need such support, you would need to implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/678801) for it to work cross-browser.*

Comment: This is the code I was typing. Simple and efficient. I would suggest to put with CSS #box {position: absolute}, instead of giving it with JS.

Comment: @enguerranws That is a good point, I'll add a small comment about that. Thanks!

Comment: I can use it as a cursor by hiding the original cursor but it doesn't show any effect on clicking can you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: @Faiz Not sure what you mean. What should happen when you click? This might be fit for a new question, perhaps.

Comment: I want to use it as a cursor so that when I click something like a link it opens it. You got me?

Comment: @Faiz Alright, that will take some work I believe. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148424/registering-clicks-on-an-element-that-is-under-another-element) might get you started. If you need further assistance, then it is probably better to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `setInterval()` for this, but `onmousemove` should do the job.

By the way, you shouldn't pass placeBox() as a string :

```
setInterval(placeBox(), 1);
```

Also, as some others said : event is undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is:

```
setInterval("placeBox()", 1);
```

Define first your `setInterval()` function, then remove the quoatation marks on `placebox()`, plus, indicate a return value in your `placebox()` function if you will use its return value for the function `setInterval()`

Maybe it should be like this:

```
setInterval(placeBox(), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function placeBox(){
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        var d = document.getElementById('box');
        d.style.position = "absolute";
        d.style.left = x+'px';
        d.style.top =  y+'px';
    }
```

event is not defined here.

```
function move(){
    //do something on mouse move
}

function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    if (elm.addEventListener) {
        elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
        return true;
    }
    else if (elm.attachEvent) {
        var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }
    else {
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    }
    else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

function init(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    addEvent(body, 'mousemove', move);
}

addLoadEvent(init);
```