# Can't manually change top/left of a draggable div?

Tags: jquery

My [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/dSc9V/4/) :

## HTML

```
<div id="score">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="myDiv">1</div>
<div class="myDiv">2</div>
<div class="myDiv">3</div>
```

## CSS

```
#score
{
    height:50px;
}

.myDiv
{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}​
```

## jQuery

```
$(".myDiv").draggable({
    start: function () {
        ImmagineDrag = $(this);
    },
    drag: function () {
        currentImageX = ImmagineDrag.position().top;
        
        $('#score').html(currentImageX);

        if(currentImageX > 200) {
            ImmagineDrag.css({ 'top': '0', 'left': '0' });
        }            
    },
    stop: function () {
    }
});​
```

as example, I want that when I drag the element over 200px (axis-y) it moves the current div at the posizion 0 0. Seems this doesnt works. How can I do/force it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've been playing with this a bit and I've got some code to get you going, I think this code is doing what you want, see the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXBjH/) .

I had to take a look at jqueryui source to find a way to do what you want, the code uses some private properties and calls a private method to achieve that. The basic idea behind my hack is I want to set  [`cursorAt`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#cursor-style) property at `drag` event time, because `cursorAt` in only evaluated by the jqueryui source on `start` drag event, so even if you changed it later the new value won't be used.

So by calling `_adjustOffsetFromHelper()` this reinterprets the parameter you pass as the new `cursorAt` property and apply it.

Now a tricky part was to figure out the correct **top** and **left** values to pass in new `cursorAt` property. I approximate them the best I could by using the private properties `.offset.click.top` and `.offset.click.left`, but for some thing the **top** didn't match and had to hardcode a value, it's probably some margin offset or the like, you could play with other private properties like `.offset.top` to try to get rid of the harcoded value.

To further improve upon this code you better have a look at the  [**draggable jqueryui source**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js) , especially the `_mouseStart()` method (the code that executes at **drag_start** time) has some positioning variables that you may find useful.

**Pasting of jsFiddle code:**

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="score">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="myDiv">1</div>
<div class="myDiv">2</div>
<div class="myDiv">3</div>
```

CSS:

```
#score
{
    height:50px;
}

.myDiv
{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}​
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var adjusted = false;
$(".myDiv").draggable({
    start: function () {
        ImmagineDrag = $(this);
        startImageX = ImmagineDrag.position().top;
        startImageY = ImmagineDrag.position().left;
    },
    drag: function () {
        currentImageX = ImmagineDrag.position().top;
        currentImageY = ImmagineDrag.position().left;

        $('#score').html(currentImageX);

        if(currentImageX > 200) {
            if (!adjusted) {
                adjusted = true;
                drg = ImmagineDrag.data("draggable");
                ctop = drg.offset.click.top;
                cleft = drg.offset.click.left;
                newtop = currentImageX - startImageX + ctop;
                newleft = currentImageY - startImageY + cleft;
                drg._adjustOffsetFromHelper({top:newtop-12,left:newleft});
            }
        }            
    },
    stop: function () {
    }
});​
```

​
​

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9QmbG/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".myDiv").draggable({
            start: function () {
                ImmagineDrag = $(this);
            },
            drag: function () {
                currentImageX = ImmagineDrag.position().top;

                $('#score').html(currentImageX);

                if(currentImageX > 200) {   
                    ImmagineDrag.css({ 'top': '0', 'left': '0' });
                    return false; 
                }            
            },
            stop: function () {
            }
    });
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730409/jquery-ui-call-start-drag-manually#answer-7881680)

Answer (score 1):

Just after your following line:

```
ImmagineDrag.css({ 'top': '0', 'left': '0' });
```

add this:

```
return false;
```

that should do what you want.

Comment: No, because I lost the "drag" function. I need to still move mouse, also if the div is far away than the mouse cursor.

Comment: Well, you've hit a wall then, because there is no mechanism for moving the mouse via JavaScript. You should think about refactoring the interaction with your ui.

Comment: No, mouse could be in the same posizion! Is the div that should move :)

Answer (score 0):

The drag handler constantly updates the position, you could move your code to the [stop handler](http://jsfiddle.net/dSc9V/7/). That way when you stop dragging it reverts to the 0,0 spot.

[The draggable plugin has built in functionality to constrain movement](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement) to an axis or a bounding element, you should use that instead.

Comment: Uhm, and how can I use it to constrain movement dynamically? (inside the drag, for example)

Comment: What do you mean by 'inside the drag'?

Comment: the drag function `drag: function () { }`. In fact, as you see in the code, if I get the >200 on Y position, I want to change "at that moment" the position of my div (don't ask to me why, its a strange scenario :))

Comment: I don't think that is possible with the existing draggable plugin. It is not implemented because it's a very weird thing to do :) Can't you sketch the situation, maybe you need a different approach

Answer (score 0):

```
var ImmagineDrag  = null,
    currentImageX = null;

$(".myDiv").draggable({
    start: function() {
        ImmagineDrag = $(this);
    },
    drag: function() {
        currentImageX = ImmagineDrag.position().top;
        $('#score').html(currentImageX);
    },
    stop: function() {
        // place your CSS code to stop function
        if (currentImageX > 200) {
            ImmagineDrag.css({
                'top': '0',
                'left': '0'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dSc9V/8/)***

Comment: Yeah, you have done it on "stop". I need it on "drag" event :)

Comment: I offered that answer 10 minutes ago, not what OP needs