# Clicking on one button to trigger click event on another

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I want to click on button 2 to trigger a click event on button 1.

However, when I try the following, nothing happens when clicking on #2: no alert for #1 or #2.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<button id="button-1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button-2">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#container').on( "click", '#button-1', function(e){
    alert('CLICKED 1');
});
$('#container').on( "click", '#button-2', function(e){
    $('#button-1').trigger(e);
    alert('CLICKED 2');
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/8RnBf/7/**

Moreover, if I put the #2 alert before the trigger, I end up with an infinite loop.

**http://jsfiddle.net/8RnBf/6/**

Why is this not working as expected?

---

**UPDATE:**

I should have made it clear: the original event must be passed. In essence, we're trying to do what was done [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091671/165673), but with delegated events

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
$('#button-1').trigger('click');
```

or

```
$('#button-1').trigger(e.type);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RnBf/17/

instead of

```
$('#button-1').trigger(e);
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8RnBf/11/)***

Read about jquery [.trigger() here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: The OP is already passing a click `event` object to `trigger`, I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: No, we need to pass the orig event, sorry that wasn't made clear

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - or `event.type` can also be used to trigger it.

Comment: @Yarin - use `e.type` to trigger the original event.

Answer (score 4):

To properly trigger a delegated event you have to create an event object and pass it to `trigger()`

```
$('#container').on( "click", '#button-2', function(e){
    var event = jQuery.Event(e.type);
    event.target = $('#button-1').get(0);

    $('#container').trigger(event);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8RnBf/14/)

That way you're actually triggering the event on the element it was bound to, passing the selector the delegated event handler will filter on as the `event.target`, so it will fire just as it would if the element was actually clicked.

Or you could use the original event if you change the event.target

```
$('#container').on( "click", '#button-1', function(e){
    alert('CLICKED 1');
});

$('#container').on( "click", '#button-2', function(e){
    e.target = $('#button-1').get(0);
    $('#container').trigger(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When you need to call click event of any button then syntax is as below

```
$('selector').trigger(event);
```

selector -> which tag's event you need to fire

event -> which event you need to fire

In your case you need to change following one line

```
$('#button-1').trigger(e);
```

here you need pass event of e like click event, select event, etc.

so solution is replace this line with any of the following line

```
$('#button-1').trigger(e.type); 

$('#button-1').trigger("click");
```